Should we have a [minecraft-april-fools] tag?
A user recently asked about one of Mojang's April Fools' Day jokes in Minecraft, specifically about accessing the potato dimension: Can I still access the potato dimension? They created a new tag, minecraft-april-fools, for their question and even submitted a tag wiki. However, another user later removed the tag from the question.
Is the minecraft-april-fools tag something we want to keep? Could it be useful for similar questions in the future?
Having a dedicated tag for these questions could help organize them and make them easier to find. On the other hand, we should consider whether these April Fools' Day features are significant enough to warrant their own tag, or if they could be adequately covered under existing tags.
What are your thoughts on this? Do you think the minecraft-april-fools tag could be helpful or useful?

They are neither a totally different game (like MCJava vs. MCBE), nor a very significant part (like redstone, commands, servers, mods, …). Searching for "minecraft april fools" gives 19 results, which is as many as the least used tag containing "minecraft", but some of those results are not actually about these snapshots or are duplicates or closed for other reasons.
I would have not deleted the tag, but I also find it not necessary to create one again now.
